# gzip 2 files into one file

Tags: command-line, tar, gzip, bzip2

I want to gzip two or more files into one file, I checked [this](https://superuser.com/questions/334827/how-to-gzip-multiple-files-into-one-gz-file/334829) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/553779/gzip-many-files-one-by-one/553780) but both have files like: `n1.txt`, `n2.txt`, ... but my filenames are completely different, like: `file.mp4`, `bar.txt`, `foo.jpeg` and I want to gzip them all and put the output into one file. This didn't help too:

```
gzip -c file.mp4 > test.gz
gzip -c bar.txt >> test.gz
```

Do I have to tar them first?

And another question: In tar files, we can watch inner files without decompression using:

```
tar -tvf filename.tar
```

Is there anyway to do this with gzip or bzip2?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unlike ZIP, RAR or 7-Zip, for example, `gzip` can only compress one file. As you’ve already noted, there is the `tar` program which can serialize multiple files into one which makes them ready for `gzip`. The traditional Unix philosophy prefers to use multiple simpler and more specialized tools than one monolithic and complicated. In this case, it results in using `tar` and `gzip` consecutively, resulting in a `.tar.gz` (or `.tgz`) file.

However, GNU `tar` includes the `-z` option which compresses the result of the traditional `tar` using `gzip` in just one command.

`.tar.gz` files are mostly created using the `-czvf` options:

- `c`reate a new archive
- g`z`ip (alternatives: `j` for bzip2, `J` for xz)
- `v`erbose (list processed files; optional)
- output `f`ile (the following argument specifies the output file)

In your example, you can use the command:

```
tar -czvf test.tar.gz file.mp4 bar.txt
```

---

> Is there any way to watch inner files without decompression with gzip or bzip2?

Yes, your command also works for a `.tar.gz` file:

```
tar -tvf test.tar.gz
```

## Further reading

- [GNU TAR Manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html)
- [10 quick tar command examples to create/extract archives in Linux](https://www.binarytides.com/linux-tar-command/)

Comment: What a great answer

Comment: The combination of two tools has also allowed the replacement of the compression method with others more efficient for a specific need.  Modern versions of tar knows many compressors and can transparently invoke them when needed.

Comment: Little known fact: It is possible to compress multiple files with `gzip`. But it's not very useful since when decompressing such a file with `gunzip` it will just append all the original files into a single file. If you type `echo Foo > a ; gzip a` you will have a file called `a.gz` which contains both the name and timestamp of the original `a` file. If you then type `echo Bar > b ; gzip b ; cat a.gz b.gz >combined.gz` you will have a `combined.gz` file which contains all the information needed to reconstruct `a` and `b` with their original names, contents, and timestamps.

Comment: _"gzip can only compress one file"_: according to [gzip file format](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1952), a gzip file can contain multiple _members_, a _member_ can then have a filename. Though, gzip util always compress single files.

Answer (score 4):

`gzip` is a compressor, not an archiver, but it works well with `tar`

```
tar -cvzf file.tar.gz path-to-files-or-directories-to-compress
```

See `man tar`

```
Compression options
   -a, --auto-compress
          Use archive suffix to determine the compression program.

   -I, --use-compress-program=COMMAND
          Filter data through COMMAND.  It must accept the -d option,  for
          decompression.  The argument can contain command line options.

   -j, --bzip2
          Filter the archive through bzip2(1).

   -J, --xz
          Filter the archive through xz(1).

   --lzip Filter the archive through lzip(1).

   --lzma Filter the archive through lzma(1).

   --lzop Filter the archive through lzop(1).

   --no-auto-compress
          Do not use archive suffix to determine the compression program.

   -z, --gzip, --gunzip, --ungzip
          Filter the archive through gzip(1).

   -Z, --compress, --uncompress
          Filter the archive through compress(1).
```

---

And yes, you can watch compressed archives the same way.